# understanding a bitwise calculation

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm reading some code that performs bitwise operations on an int and stores them in an array. I've worked out the binary representation of each step and included this beside the code.

On another computer, the array buff is received as a message and displayed in hex as `[42,56,da,1,0,0]`

Why question is, how could you figure out what the original number was from the hex number. I get that `42` and `56` are the ASCII equivalent of `'B'` and `'V'`. But how do you get the number `423` from `da` `'1'` `'0'` `'0'`?

Thanks

Comment: To be exact, 42 and 56 are the *hex* ASCII representation of `B` and `V`, respectively. Or 0x42 and 0x56, to be more clear and concise.

Comment: Note: If `int` is 16-bit, `reading>>16` and `reading>>16` are not defined.

Comment: @chux: Sorry, I only thought about the left side operand. You are right about the right side, of course. My bad!

Answer (score 5):

`DA 01 00 00` is the little endian representation of `0x000001DA` or just `0x1DA`. This, in turn, is 256 + 13 * 16 + 10 = 474. Maybe you had this number and changed the program later and forgot to recompile?

Seen it from the other side, 423 is 0x1a7…

Comment: thanks that is very helpful. Could I ask another question - why is there the need to perform this bitwise operations to put the numbers in the array? I am wondering why the code is like this? thanks

Comment: @pelican Counter question: How else would you do it? How would you get the 2nd or 3rd byte out of a value which spans multiple bytes? The only way is shifting the number so that the wanted part is in the lower 8 bits and then cutting them out. Ok, you could reverse these steps and do `buff[5] = (reading & FF000000) >>24;` but that would be more dangerous, because it can lead to mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

as glgl says it should be a7, you can see where that comes from

```
  buff[2] = reading&0xff; // 10100111            = 0xa7
  buff[3] = (reading>>8)&0xff; //00000001        = 1
  buff[4] = (reading>>16)&0xff; //00000000       = 0
  buff[5] = (reading>>24)&0xff; ////00000000     = 0
```